# How to handle one-to-one association with unique constraints in both models in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have two models, `User` and `Profile` and a form for a new user that has `inputs_for` for the profile's username field.

Here's the code for those:

user ->

```
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :crypted_password, :string    

    has_one :profile, MyApp.Profile

    timestamps
  end

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(email password), ~w())
    |> validate_length(:email, min: 5, max: 240)
    |> validate_format(:email, ~r/\w+\@\w+\.\w+/)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)    
    |> validate_confirmation(:password)
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 8, max: 240)    
  end
end
```

profile ->

```
defmodule MyApp.Profile do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "profiles" do
    field :username, :string    

    belongs_to :user, MyApp.User, foreign_key: :user_id

    timestamps
  end

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(username), ~w())
    |> validate_length(:username, min: 4, max: 240)
    |> unique_constraint(:username)      
  end

end
```

controller create method's code ->

```
  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do    
    profile_changeset = Profile.changeset(%Profile{}, user_params["profile"])
    user_changeset = User.changeset(%User{profile: profile_changeset}, user_params)
    case Repo.insert(user_changeset) do
      {:ok, _changeset} ->        
        redirect conn, to: main_page_path(conn, :index)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render conn, "new.html", user_changeset: changeset
    end
  end
```

Could somebody help me with the code for controller that creates `user` and `profile` in a transaction and if validations fail, renders the form again with errors? The main struggle for me is showing errors that I get from uniqueness constraints, which get added only during the `Repo` insertion and thus `valid?` method doesn't add them ...

I've spent a few hours trying to make it work but I can't do it properly, when some things work the other don't ...

Comment: This is a short answer because I am short on time. You don't need to worry about transactions if you are using `inputs_for` and changesets. Inside `inputs_for`, all the errors will be in `profile_form.errors` (the one given to the `inputs_for` function). You can list the profile errors exactly how would you list them in the user model. Check this blog post for more info: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/

Comment: @José Valim, Thank you for the reply. I have added code that I I have in my controller to the question and it doesn't work properly. I tried to wrap it in a transaction, I tried to use `build` method for profile and I tried to work with the `valid?` method before insertion and other things, but I can't make it work properly. I've read that article like 100 times but still havent figured the right way out.

Comment: @José Valim, I apologize I was inaccurate, displaying errors in the form works great, the problem is with adding those errors ...

Comment: Read the blog post, they code you have defined should just work. Keep in mind though that unique_constraints require you to add `create unique_index(...)` to your migrations. Please check the docs.

Comment: @José Valim, Well, if I use the code for the controller above then it works like this: 1) If I send an empty form, It runs all validations except unique constraints, adds errors to the changeset and renders the form again with errors. 2) When I correct all usual errors (which are probably checked with `valid?`), it checks unique constraints and if, for example, email is already taken, renders the form again with an error for the email field. 3) When I correct unique constraints errors, it starts a transaction and saves ONLY `user's` info, without `profille`. And I have the index, thank you

Comment: This is really weird, it should definitely save both. Is your application on github? If not, can you put an app that reproduces the issue on github?

Comment: @JoséValim there -> https://github.com/JustMikey/phoenix-test-app , if it's just some silly mistake from my side, then I apologize for taking your time

Comment: Please try these changes and update the repo: https://gist.github.com/josevalim/3efdc77c440e76b6513f If they do not work, i can run the code tomorrow. :)

Comment: @JoséValim It worked :) As I said earlier, I apologize for taking so much of your time, thank you very much :) Hopefully it will be helpful not only to me. You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it, if you want to.

Comment: @JoséValim One more question :) I think it automatically uses `changeset` method of the `profile` model, so I wonder if there is a way to change the changeset that I want to use for the `profile` model? Like to use `my_changeset` instead of `changeset` or something like that ?

Comment: Yes, the blog post I linked above tells exactly how to do it. Have you read it? There is a `on_cast` configuration you can use when declaring the association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in your controller action:

```
profile_changeset = Profile.changeset(%Profile{}, user_params["profile"])
user_changeset = User.changeset(%User{profile: profile_changeset}, user_params)
```

Instead of building the profile changeset on your own and setting it directly in the user (which is wrong, the User should store a profile, not a profile changesets), you should just pass everything in:

```
user_changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)
```

And then tell the user to automatically cast the profile changeset for you by declaring "profile" as a required field:

```
|> cast(params, ~w(email password profile), ~w())
```

We will push a fix to master so we at least raise an error in those cases.

Comment: Does putting `profile` in the list of required fields make sure it is always present? Will it add an error if `user_params` does not contain nested `profile` params? And if not, should I validate `profile` presence like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073275/ecto-validate-presence-of-associated-model or there is a better way?

Comment: Yes to the first two questions. Which invalidate the last question. :)